# Perform an eSIM swap

Tags: android

I am trying to enable an eSIM swap in the application that belongs to the telecommunication company I work for and I have some questions before I start.

for now, I have this:

```
static final String ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION = "download_subscription";
static final String LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION = "test.esim.app.lpa.permission.BROADCAST";
BroadcastReceiver receiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (!ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    return;
                }
                resultCode = getResultCode();
                detailedCode = intent.getIntExtra(EuiccManager.EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILED_CODE, 0);
                resultIntent = intent;
            }
        };
context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION),LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION,null);
DownloadableSubscription sub = DownloadableSubscription.forActivationCode(encodedActivationCode);
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION);
PendingIntent callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mgr.downloadSubscription(sub, false , callbackIntent);
```

1. In LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION, I just need to attach my application id to ".lpa.permission.BROADCAST" since I am not a device OEM. Is it right?
2. The encodedActivationCode, this I will need the back-end/API to send it to me right?
3. How to verify the state of downloading profile, was it a success or a failure, and what is the failure.
4. AS I've been requested, they don't want to swape/switch, so I made it false in downloadSubscription, and from my understanding after the download, I have to perform the below, from where I can get the subscriptionId.

```java
static final String ACTION_SWITCH_TO_SUBSCRIPTION = "switch_to_subscription";
static final String LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION = "test.esim.app.lpa.permission.BROADCAST";
BroadcastReceiver receiver =
        new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (!LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                    return;
                }
                resultCode = getResultCode();
                detailedCode = intent.getIntExtra(EuiccManager.EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILED_CODE, 0);
                resultIntent = intent;
            }
        };
context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_SWITCH_TO_SUBSCRIPTION), LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION , null);
Intent intent = new Intent(LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION);
PendingIntent callbackIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0 , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
mgr.switchToSubscription(subscriptionId, callbackIntent);
```

Comment: Hey! Have you succeded with e-sim activation process? We are trying to do the same approach, but faced the situation when getResultCode() == 2 and intent doesn`t have a EuiccManager.EXTRA_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTION_DETAILED_CODE additional error...

Comment: @AntonDerevyanko Hi, just saw your comment, if you still have the issue please contact me at bhsn1895@gmail.com

Comment: @EssamAdel  I'm working on same feature where I want to download and activate eSim (switch) for my companies pre and postpaid apps. I just started looking into this, we don't have a LPA app so I'm not sure what permission to declare at LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION. Do you have this feature working ? i'd be very keen to know

Comment: @AntonDerevyanko have you got this working?  I have to do the same for my carrier company too

Comment: @Mohammed - yes, our team had managed this... Right now I don't remember details, but it seems we needed to somehow contact sim-operator and change the subscription signature

Comment: @AntonDerevyanko Thanks, I figured it out once I connected with our Network guy. I gave him our app SHA256 signature string which he has to put in Metadata of SMDP+ service, Then when we call downloadSubscription api app will get runtime permission to install the subscription profile. It was quite fun discovering it all.

Comment: Hi, I'm facing the same issue while trying to enable an eSIM swap (download and activate esim) and do not really understand what I am missing. Is LPA_DECLARED_PERMISSION mandatory? If so, wheere should I get it from? 

@Mohammed mentioned that he gave the SHA256 to be added to the Metadata of SMDP+. I'm also working on this